# Why is the superclass designated initializer getting called by default?

Tags: ios, swift, oop, inheritance

I am new to Swift and getting some problem regarding initializers. I have created a Swift file with the following code :

```
import Foundation

class SuperClass
{
    var a : Int
    init()
    {
        a = 10
        print("In Superclass")
    }
}

class SubClass : SuperClass
{
    override init()
    {
        print("In Subclass")
    }
}
```

In the above code, `init()` of `SubClass` does not contain call to `init()` of `SuperClass` i.e. there is no `super.init()` in `SubClass init()`.

So my question is:

**1.** Why is it not giving any error if I don't call designated `init()` of `SuperClass`

**2.** If I am creating an object of `SubClass` i.e. `let s = SubClass()`, the output is :

```
In Subclass

In Superclass
```

Why the `init()` of `SuperClass` is getting called? Does a subclass init() calls the superclass init() by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why the `init()` of SuperClass is getting called? Does a subclass `init()` calls the superclass `init()` by default?

Basically, yes.

If all the rules say that you should say `super.init()` and you don't say it, it is called for you.

I don't like this behavior; it is poorly documented, and besides, secretly doing stuff for you seems against the spirit of Swift. But I filed a bug against it long ago and was told it was intended behavior.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understood your question, you're not only wondering why, when and how the initializer gets called automatically, but also complaining about the missing documentation of this behavior.

First of all I agree with you on the lack of documentation - just like you I'm not able to find anything about this behavior and therefore it should be added to the documentation by Apple.

**Why `super.init()` is called:**

As per documentation a designated initializer of the superclass has to be called by a designated initializer of its subclass in order to fully initialize all properties.

> **Rule 1**
>
> A designated initializer must call a designated initializer from its
>   immediate superclass.

Your code example above proves it's obviously done implicitly: `print("In Superclass")` prints to the console, so `super.init()` is somehow invoked while creating an instance.

**When and how `super.init()` is called:**

There are some conditions to be met in order to allow the compiler to call the designated initializer of the superclass implicitly:

1. The superclass must have only **one** designated initializer which
   is then called. Otherwise the compiler had to choose one to delegate
   to. This single designated initializer could be also the default
   initializer or an inherited initializer.

   ```
   class SuperClass {
       var a: Int
       init() {
           a = 10
       }
       // introduction of a second designated initializer in superclass:
       init(withValue value: Int) {
           a = value
       }
   }

   class SubClass: SuperClass {
       // won't compile:
       // "error: super.init isn't called on all paths before returning from initializer"            
       override init() {}
   }
   ```
2. The single designated initializer of the superclass mustn't have any
   parameters. After all the compiler wouldn't know any appropriate
   parameter to be passed.

   ```
   class SuperClass {
       var a: Int
       // declaration of an initializer with parameter:
       init(withValue value: Int) {
           a = value
       }
   }

   class SubClass: SuperClass {
       // won't compile:
       // "error: super.init isn't called on all paths before returning from initializer"            
       override init() {}
   }
   ```
3. The designated initializer of the subclass mustn't further read or
   modify (inherited) instance properties of the superclass or call
   instance methods of the superclass. That's because of Swift's
   two-phase initialization process with its corresponding safety
   checks and the fact that the implicit delegation up to the designated
   initializer of the superclass happens at the end of the
   `init`-Statement in the subclass.

   > **Safety check 2**
   >
   > A designated initializer must delegate up to a
   >   superclass initializer before assigning a value to an inherited
   >   property. If it doesn’t, the new value the designated initializer
   >   assigns will be overwritten by the superclass as part of its own
   >   initialization.“
   >
   > **Safety check 4**
   >
   > An initializer cannot call any instance methods, read
   >   the values of any instance properties, or refer to self as a value
   >   until after the first phase of initialization is complete.

   ```
   class SuperClass {
       var a: Int
       init() {
           a = 10
       }
   }

   class SubClass: SuperClass {
       // won't compile:
       // "error: use of 'self' in property access 'a' before super.init initializes self"            
       override init() {
           a = 10 // modifying inherited self.a before phase 1 of initialization completes isn't valid! 
           // implicit delegation to super.init()
       }
   }
   ```

   > **Safety check 1**
   >
   > A designated initializer must ensure that all of the
   >   properties introduced by its class are initialized before it
   >   delegates up to a superclass initializer.

   ```
   class SuperClass {
       var a: Int
       init() {
           a = 10
       }
   }

   class SubClass: SuperClass {
       // introduction of instance property "b"
       var b: Int
       // compiles finely:
       override init() {
           b = 10 // initializing self.b is required before delegation!
           // implicit delegation to super.init()
       }
   }
   ```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Every class have at least one *designated initializer* which is responsible for initializing instance variables.

Here is an extract from the doc :

> Classes tend to have very few designated initializers, and it is quite common for a class to have only one. Designated initializers are “funnel” points through which initialization takes place, and through which the initialization process continues up the superclass chain.
>
> Every class must have at least one designated initializer. In some cases, this requirement is satisfied by inheriting one or more designated initializers from a superclass, as described in [Automatic Initializer Inheritance](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID222) below.

You can refer to the complete documentation for further details : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html

**A rule of thumb**

1. Create one designated initializer for your class.
2. Call the designated initializer of the superclass or let the system figure this out for you.
3. Create zero or more convenience initializers which will call your designated initializer.

Comment: But the superclass initializers are not inherited if we give our own designated initializers in the subclass. And why is it getting called by default?

Comment: If you give your own designated initializers, you must call a designated initializer of the superclass. If you do not, the compiler will choose one for you because the superclass instance variables must be initialized !

Answer (score 1):

You are not accessing the super class variable in the subclass hence super.init() is called followed by the subclass's init. But if you were to try using the super class variable in subclass without calling its initialiser then it will result in a compile time error.

Comment: [Apple documentation][https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID203]] says that subclass must call super class designated initializer. Can you support your statement with any proof?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try this myself, but the [Swift Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID203) says:

> **Initializer Delegation for Class Types**
>
> To simplify the relationships between designated and convenience initializers, Swift applies the following three rules for delegation calls between initializers:
>
> **Rule 1**
>
> A designated initializer must call a designated initializer from its immediate superclass.
>
> **Rule 2**
>
> A convenience initializer must call another initializer from the same class.
>
> **Rule 3**
>
> A convenience initializer must ultimately call a designated initializer.
>
> *A simple way to remember this is:*
>
> *Designated initializers must always delegate up.*
>
> *Convenience initializers must always delegate across.*

So, as it is a 'rule' to call `super.init()`, it might just be done internally, if not implemented explicitly.

Comment: But its nowhere written that it is called internally.

Comment: You can also have a look at the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25257224/does-a-swift-subclass-always-have-to-call-super-init

Comment: I read the post..but still the answers doesn't give any proof of super.init() being called internally..