# Error in Swift class: Property not initialized at super.init call - How to initialize properties which need use of self in their initializer parameter

Tags: ios, swift, properties, compiler-errors, initialization

I am overriding a `UITableViewController` in swift, in which I have two required variables which are initialized by using a `weak` reference of `self` since these are used to implement `UITableViewDataSource` protocol and need `self` reference to use its `tableView` property

```
class VideosListViewController: UITableViewController {
  
  required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.datasourceOfflineVideos = ASDataSource(tableViewController: self)
    self.datasourceOnlineVideos = ASDataSource(tableViewController: self)
  }
  
  // MARK: - Variables
  var datasourceOnlineVideos:ASDataSource
  var datasourceOfflineVideos:ASDataSource
  }
```

Now the problem is as it is giving me error `Property not initialized at super.init call` which is expected as explained here: [Error in Swift class: Property not initialized at super.init call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24021093/error-in-swift-class-property-not-initialized-at-super-init-call).

> Swift’s compiler performs four helpful safety-checks to make sure that two-phase initialization is completed without error
>
> Safety check 1 A designated initializer must ensure that all of the “properties introduced by its class are initialized before it delegates up to a superclass initializer.
>
> Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks. https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/swift-programming-language/id881256329?mt=11

So my question is:

**If an instance variable in swift class needs `self` reference to be initialized like `ASDataSource` type  variables here, how can I do that??**

**Since swift doesn't allow me call the `super.init()` before initiazing all the instance variables And also doesn't allow me to user `self` within the initializer in the `init()` before calling `super.init()`**

Currently I am using optional variable(s) to resolve the issue. But for learning purpose I want to know how to do that. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just have to invert the order super.init/properties in your initializer:

```
 required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.datasourceOfflineVideos = ASDataSource(tableViewController: self)
    self.datasourceOnlineVideos = ASDataSource(tableViewController: self)
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
  }
```

instance properties comes first, then the superclass initializer can be invoked. But that's not possible in your case, because you are referencing `self`.

The workaround in this case is to make the properties implicitly unwrapped optionals:

```
var datasourceOnlineVideos:ASDataSource!
var datasourceOfflineVideos:ASDataSource!
```

Since optionals don't need to be initialized, you can safely initialize them after the `super.init` method has been called. Being implicitly unwrapped, you use them as any other non optional property.

This pattern is used by Apple in several classes, including `UIViewController`: when you add an outlet from IB, the component property is always declared as implicitly unwrapped. That's because the control itself is not instantiated in the initializer, but at a later stage.

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me :) One more thing: In this case we need to call super.init before initializing datasource variables.