# iOS swift Singleton init method

Tags: ios, sockets, swift, singleton

I'm writing a singleton class to access socket by adopting [socket.IO-objc](https://github.com/pkyeck/socket.IO-objc), here's what I did so far:

```
class Singleton_SocketManager: NSObject, SocketIODelegate {
    var isSocketConnected: Bool = false
    var socket: SocketIO

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    class var sharedInstance: Singleton_SocketManager {
        struct Static {
            static var onceToken: dispatch_once_t = 0
            static var instance: Singleton_SocketManager? = nil
        }
        dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
            Static.instance = Singleton_SocketManager()
        }
        return Static.instance!
    }
}
```

Yet the compiler complains:

```
Property 'self.socket' not initialized at super.init call
```

How should I write my init method here to make the compilation error go away?

By the way, I transitioned the code above from objective-c, in obj-c, the SocketIO is initialized like so:

```
    self.socket = [[SocketIO alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
```

And If I put the init method this way:

```
    override init() {
    self.socket = SocketIO(delegate: self)
    super.init()
}
```

It complains:

```
self used before super.init call
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it necessary to inherit from NSObject for your application? I ran into a similar situation where I needed to set the Singleton as a delegate (so I needed self). By not inheriting from NSObject, my issue was resolved - no need to call super.init() anyway then

[Apple's](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#singleton) recommendation for a Singleton is like this :

If you need to perform additional setup beyond initialization, you can assign the result of the invocation of a closure to the global constant:

```
class Singleton {
    static let sharedInstance: Singleton = {
        let instance = Singleton()
        // setup code
        return instance
    }()
}
```

But a (I think) more recent syntax can also be found on their [swift blog](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=7), which I prefer :

```
class Singleton {
    static let sharedInstance = Singleton()

    private init() {
        // do your init here
        print("Singleton created")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quote from The Swift Programming Language, which answers your question:

> “Swift’s compiler performs four helpful safety-checks to make sure
>   that two-phase initialization is completed without error:”
>
> Safety check 1 “A designated initializer must ensure that all of the
>   “properties introduced by its class are initialized before it
>   delegates up to a superclass initializer.”
>
> Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks.
>   https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/swift-programming-language/id881256329?mt=11

Credits: [Ruben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1267793/ruben) on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24021093/error-in-swift-class-property-not-initialized-at-super-init-call)

Another solution is to make the 'socket' variable unwrapped optional.

```
var socket:IOSocket!
```

Comment: @dulan why don't you make the 'socket' variable optional?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below option as suggested in the below url 
[Error in Swift class: Property not initialized at super.init call - How to initialize properties which need use of self in their initializer parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27028813/error-in-swift-class-property-not-initialized-at-super-init-call-how-to-initi)
var socket: SocketIO!