# how to initialize properties in a singleton instance with swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to create a chat service singleton in swift and getting some errors initializing properties.  If I do it this way I get the error `self.client not initialized at super.init call`

```
class ChatService : NSObject, PTPusherDelegate {

    var client:PTPusher
    static let sharedInstance = ChatService()

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.client = PTPusher.pusherWithKey("test", delegate: self) as! PTPusher
        client.connect()
    }
}
```

However if I move it before the super.init call I get `self used before super.init call`

```
override init() {
    self.client = PTPusher.pusherWithKey("test", delegate: self) as! PTPusher
    super.init()
    client.connect()
}
```

I can declare var client:PTPusher? as optional, but it's really not optional and don't want to always append an exclamation mark to client!

What's the recommended way of doing this?  I saw this stack overflow question:

[Error in Swift class: Property not initialized at super.init call - How to initialize properties which need use of self in their initializer parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27028813/error-in-swift-class-property-not-initialized-at-super-init-call-how-to-initi)

That seems to address the same topic and it suggests to invert the order of initializing properties like in my second example, but I still get an error.

Comment: Declaring client as implicitly unwrapped optional (as explained in the answer to the referenced question) should solve the problem.

Comment: ah yes indeed, I mis-read the answer the first time around.  I'll close this question.