# Swift initialize stored property issue

Tags: ios, swift

I have a class

```
class Service: NSObject {
  let wirlessSerivce: WirlessSerivce

  override init()
  {
    super.init()
    wirlessSerivce = WirlessSerivce()
    wirlessSerivce.delegate.addDelegate(self)
  }
}
```

I got these two issues:

1. `Property 'self.wirlessSerivce' not initialized at super.init call`
2. `Immutable value 'self.wirlessSerivce' may only be initialized once (change let to var)`

The goal I want to achieve is create `wirlessSerivce` and subscribe `Service` class to `wirlessSerivce` updates via delegate. I use multicast delegate and want to notify my `Service` if some data changes in `wirlessSerivce`

Also can I do something like this:

```
 class Service: NSObject {
      let wirlessSerivce =  WirlessSerivce() {
        didSet {
          wirlessSerivce.delegate.addDelegate(self)
        }
}
```

As I understood let wirlessSerivce = WirlessSerivce() will create an instance even before class gets its initialize method. Right?

Seems this code works:

```
class Service: NSObject {
  var wirlessSerivce: WirlessSerivce!

  override init()
  {
    super.init()
    wirlessSerivce = WirlessSerivce()
    wirlessSerivce.delegate.addDelegate(self)
  }
}
```

but here are few issues: var is for mutable properties and I don't need mutable service actually. `(!)` says that instance will be initialized before use it from anywhere. But I initialize it in `init` func, do I really need to mark it with `(!)`

Comment: Move `super.init()` to the end of your init method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24021093/error-in-swift-class-property-not-initialized-at-super-init-call.

Comment: you probably want to name the variable `wirelessService`, or is that some other language?

Comment: @MartinR yea I guess you're right) thanks

Comment: @simpleBob, not sure what you meant, it's a simple property name

Comment: @MatrosovAlexander `wirlessSerivce` is not the same as `wirelessService`

Comment: @simpleBob, oh, yea exactly, my fault, thanks for grammar correction, yea this is exactly what I meant.