# Using methods in the required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following in my View Controller:

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    selectedFocusAreas = Array()
    for _ in 0...focusAreas.count {
        selectedFocusAreas.append(false)
    }

    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!

}
```

This code compiles and doesn't give me any issues. However, when I try extract the code into a method like so:

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        setUpSelectedFocusAreaData()
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    }

    func setUpSelectedFocusAreaData(){
        selectedFocusAreas = Array()
        for _ in 0...focusAreas.count {
            selectedFocusAreas.append(false)
        }
    }
```

I get the following compilation errors:

- Use of `self` in method call `setUpSelectedFocusAreaData` before `super.init` initializes self
- Property `self.selectedFocusAreas` not initialized at `super.init` call

Is there a way to have a method be called in the init method?

Comment: Initialise `selectedFocusAreas` when you declare the property or in your initialiser and then call the function after you call `super.init`

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/24114372/2707648

Comment: Be aware that your array contains one extraneous item. It's supposed to be either `0...focusAreas.count - 1` or `0..<focusAreas.count`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Paulw11 was on the money, you have to do the following:

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        selectedFocusAreas = Array()
        setUpSelectedFocusAreaData()
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    }

    func setUpSelectedFocusAreaData(){
        for _ in 0...focusAreas.count {
            selectedFocusAreas.append(false)
        }
    }
```

i.e initialize the value first and then call the method.