# There is an error in my code: not initialized at super.init call

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

Tell me what am I doing wrong? why is the error happening in my code? I can't figure it out, an error like this appears : not initialized at super.init call

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yA9MW.png)

I can't find any information, I will be grateful for any help, maybe it will be useful to someone in the future too

```
import AVKit
import SwiftUI


class UIVideoPlayer: UIView {
var videoURL : String
var playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    
    super.init(frame: frame)
    
    
    
    guard let url = URL(string: videoURL) else { return }

    let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
    //self.player = player
    player.isMuted = true
    player.play()
    
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player.currentItem, queue: .main) { _ in
                    player.seek(to: CMTime.zero)
                    player.play()
        


    }
  
    playerLayer.player = player
    playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity(rawValue: AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill.rawValue)
    
    layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    playerLayer.frame = bounds
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

}

struct PlayersView: UIViewRepresentable {

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIVideoPlayer {
    return UIVideoPlayer()
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIVideoPlayer, context: Context) {
    
}
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error in Swift class: Property not initialized at super.init call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24021093/error-in-swift-class-property-not-initialized-at-super-init-call)

Comment: I do not understand how to implement this using my code example (

Comment: It's unclear what you want or expect. How is `videoURL` ever supposed to get set, if you don't set it?

Comment: to download a lot of videos from modal

Comment: You may _say_ that, but I do not _see_ you ever giving `videoURL` a value. You need to think about where this value is supposed to come from. Until you do, it is impossible to make sense of your code.

Answer (score 0):

#### As you declared "videoURL" as store property

> Initialization is the process of preparing an instance of a class, structure, or enumeration for use. This process involves setting an initial value for each stored property on that instance and performing any other setup or initialization that’s required before the new instance is ready for use.

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html

so, you can solve this by using "Explicitly unwrapped Optional"

```
var videoURL : String!
```

Or you can declare videoURL as Optional

```
var videoURL : String?
```

Or assign initial value to "videoURL" before calling Super.init

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
self.videoURL = "Your URL"
super.init(frame: frame)
```

> Class initialization in Swift is a two-phase process. In the first phase, each stored property is assigned an initial value by the class that introduced it. Once the initial state for every stored property has been determined, the second phase begins, and each class is given the opportunity to customize its stored properties further before the new instance is considered ready for use.

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html#ID216

Comment: thanks for your answer, but this is a single link, and I need to download a large number of links that I get from the model

Comment: this is what I need to get in the end

     `struct ContentView: View {
var video: Video
      var body: some View {
        PlayersView(videoURL: video.wp)
    }
    }`

Comment: You can create your own Initializers : 
'
convenience init(with frame:CGRect ,videoUrls: [URL]) {
    //----- Perform your operation


 // Call designated
   self.init(frame: CGRect)

}'

Comment: So, Now what issue are you facing?

Comment: It's hard for me to figure it out, I'm new to SWIFTUI, could you show it with my code example? I need not one video link, but many, I have a data model with different links, and I need to get video links from there

Comment: Okay, after abstracting the URL what operation you are performing if you are not showing anything on view then we can create simple function which will return all abstract URLs.

Comment: I can somehow contact you to tell you more, I have a very large project, and I cannot place it here in full